# How to append vue.js event to existing html element

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is there any way to append vue.js events to existing html elements?

HTML elements:

```html
<div class="borrow-button">Borrow</div>
<div class="borrow-button">Borrow</div>
<div class="borrow-button">Borrow</div>
```

Can I somehow add vue.js event to this divs?

```
$('.borrow-button').each(function(i, obj) {
    //how to append for example onclick event to this divs? (onclick="borrow")
});
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @saurabh 
Im using jsgrid to generate table with data, so html elements are already created. When I create in jsgrid div with vue.js event, it doesn't work, so my idea was to append event to this created divs.

Comment: You can't add vue events to HTML vue does not compile. You can add regular js events with jquery or plain js

Answer (score 3):

I am currently not aware of any vue way of doing this. But as `jsgrid` uses jquery, you can use [event handler attachment](http://api.jquery.com/on/) of it to bind vue methods.

Here is an exmple:

```
var demo = new Vue({
    el: '#demo',
    data: function(){
        return {
      };
    },
    methods:{
      myMethod () {
        alert('Do whatever you wanns do')
      }
    },
    mounted () {
        $("#myBtn").on('click', this.myMethod);
    }
})
```

You can check this code working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mimani/90g9nLgy/).

Answer (score 2):

If vue instance is called vm you can use a method inside it to fire the event like this

```
// Vue Instance
var vm = new Vue({
  methods: {
      handleButton: function(i, obj) {
        //Do whatever you want
      }
  }
})

$('.borrow-button').each(function(i, obj) {
    vm.handleButton(i, obj)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

VueJS does not provide you this possibility as the purpose is different.

You would need to use Vanilla JS inside the Vue.